# Invalid use of Matcher while Creating build Junit

Tags: java, mockito, junit5, java-17

After upgrading JDK 1.8 to 17 some of the Junit are giving error while Creating build however when  run that Junit independently its working fine .

```
public class MyClassTest{
@InjectMocks
MyClass myClass;
@Mock
AlertRuleMappingUtility alertRuleMappingUtility;
AutoCloseable closeable;
@Before
public void setUp()  {
    closeable = MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
}
@AfterEach
public void close() throws Exception {
      closeable.close();
  }
@Test
public void getDescriptionTextTest0()  throws Throwable  {
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("alert.secured_borrowings", "xyz");
myClass.setAlertType("secured_borroWings");
doReturn(map).when(alertRuleMappingUtility).fetchAlertTypeAndLongDescMapping(any());
String result = myClass.getDescriptionText();
assertNotNull(result);
}
}
```

Error i'm getting is `ERROR]   MyclassTest.setUp:31 InvalidUseOfMatchers Misplaced or mis... [INFO] [ERROR] Tests run: 750, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0`

Comment: Please intent your code properly and add the complete error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see, you mix junt4 and junit5

`@Before` is junit4

`@AfterEach` is junit5

You should change
`@Before` to `@BeforeEach`

Comment: Thanks for your time Jens after applying `@BeforeEach` , `@InjectMocks` is giving null

Comment: @Anukul what is giving null?